# Should the marginal effect of a model which includes interactions be the marginal effect of a model without interactions?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, marginal-effect

When companies run an AB test, stakeholders will often ask two questions:

i) What was the effect of the intervention, and

ii) Did the effect vary by strata (e.g. mobile vs. desktop)

Additionally, the effect is typically reported as a "relative lift".  When the outcome is binary, this is most easily understood as the relative risk of the outcome.

Stratification is one way to approach the problem, however there is no way to test if $\beta_k=0$ for all strata $k=0\dots K$.  If we instead include an interaction between the variable which identifies strata and the treatment, we can perform such a test (e.g. Likelihood ratio test, or similar omnibus tests) but now it is harder to answer what the effect of the treatment was (because it varies by strata).

Marginal effects seem like a reasonable solution.  Simply estimate an interaction model and report the marginal effect of the treatment.  Assuming the prevalence of each strata is an unbiased estimate of the prevalence in the population, my intuition says this should work.  And indeed, when I simulate this I find that the marginal effect of the treatment in the interaction model is the same as the marginal effect of the treatment in the model which excludes interactions.  Show below is a code example in R.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(marginaleffects)

N <- 100000
txt <- sample(
  c('Treatment','Control'),
  size=N,
  replace=TRUE
)

device <- sample(
  c('Desktop','Mobile','Tablet'),
  size=N,
  replace=TRUE,
  prob = c(0.6, 0.39, 0.01)
)

day <- sample(
  1:7, 
  size=N,
  replace = TRUE
)

X <- model.matrix( ~ txt*device + factor(day))

beta <- c(log(0.08), 0.02, -0.1, -0.15,
          0, 0, 0, 0, -0.5, -0.5, 
          0.03, 0.01)

linpred <- X %*% beta
y <- rbinom(N, 1, exp(linpred))

d <- tibble(txt, device, day, y) 

md <- d %>% 
  group_by(
    txt, device, day
  ) %>% 
  summarise(
    y = sum(y),
    n = n()
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()

ggplot(d, aes(day, y, color=txt)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.data = \(x) mean_se(x, 2)) + 
  facet_wrap(~device)

f1 <- glm(y ~ txt + device + day, data=d, family = binomial())
f2 <- glm(y ~ txt*device + day, data=d, family = binomial())

comparisons(
  f1, 
  variables = 'txt',
  transform_pre = 'lnratioavg',
  transform_post = exp
) %>% 
  summary

comparisons(
  f2, 
  variables = 'txt',
  transform_pre = 'lnratioavg',
  transform_post = exp
) %>% 
  summary
```

### Question

Is my intuition right, and if so how can I put some rigor behind it? Is there a proof that the two marginal effects of the treatment should be the same?  Under what conditions -- if any --  would they fail to be the same?

Comment: After doing some thinking, I think this is true by appealing to the law of total expectation.

Comment: Then maybe you can self-answer?